# Strang Issue with MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, function, count

I am trying to find the count of rows returned by below query:

```
SELECT Count(id) AS fcount, 
       user_id 
FROM   customer_followups 
WHERE  id > 0 
       AND Date(followup_date) >= Str_to_date("24-09-2012", "%d-%m-%y") 
       AND Date(followup_date) <= Str_to_date("24-09-2012", "%d-%m-%y") 
GROUP  BY user_id 
ORDER  BY user_id
```

It returns me 5 Rows.

However if I fire the query WITHOUT the count function I only get one record. See below:

```
SELECT id, 
       user_id 
FROM   customer_followups 
WHERE  id > 0 
       AND Date(followup_date) >= Str_to_date("24-09-2012", "%d-%m-%y") 
       AND Date(followup_date) <= Str_to_date("24-09-2012", "%d-%m-%y") 
GROUP  BY user_id 
ORDER  BY user_id
```

What could be the reason? ideally the count should return 1 ??

Comment: `COUNT` counts the rows which are unified by `GROUP`.

Comment: @RavIncredible: Both these queries should return the same number of rows. That number should the same as the different `user_id` in the table. The second query is rather useless though, as it will return a (more or less) random `id` per user.

Comment: Yes and I am 100% sure there is only one record for 24 Sep 2012. BUt still it fails with MYSQL and returns 5 with count function.

Answer (score 1):

[`COUNT`](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlcount.php) gives you the number of the records for a group which satisfies the condition.

```
The COUNT function is an aggregate function that simply counts all the items that
are in a group.
```

Whereas in your second query you just find the id and user_id for that group. Remember if the group has different user-id it will return any of them to find all the user_id you can use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/mysql-the-group_concat-function/) i.e. GROUP_CONCAT(user_id)

Comment: Yes I understand how count works and for the above query there is only 1 record for the mentioned date range.